# Discord Bot (python) - copying part of a message in autorespond

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, message

I'm trying to get a Discord bot to respond to a message with part of said message.
I want it to respond to
"My name is [name]"
with
"Hi, [name]!"
and a few similar instances.

Right now I have it set up to respond to messages, which works fine. This is what I'm using:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if client.user.id != message.author.id:
        if "My name is" in message.content:
          await message.channel.send("Hi!")
```

I haven't the first idea where to start with pulling the next word from the message and responding appropriately. Any advice would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could try it like this:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if client.user.id != message.author.id:
        # Split the message content into words
        words = message.content.split()

        # Check if the message starts with "My name is" and has at least one more word
        if len(words) >= 4 and words[0] == "My" and words[1] == "name" and words[2] == "is":
            # Get the name from the message
            name = " ".join(words[3:])
            
            # Send a response
            response = f"Hi, {name}!"
        await message.channel.send(response)
```

It's not super robust though, typos or different sentence structure would trip it up.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by taking the message apart. The first part is "My name is" and everything after will be stored as a variable:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message:discord.Message):
    if client.user.id != message.author.id:
        if "My name is" in message.content:
          name = message.content.split("My name is", 1)[1].strip()
          await message.channel.send(f"Hi {name}!")
```

`name` stores everything after "My name is" as the name given.